# Stripe processing error on submit, though transaction is successful

Tags: coffeescript, stripe-payments

I can't work out why I'm getting this error from Stripe on submission of my form:

`An unexpected error has occurred submitting your credit card to our secure credit card processor. This may be due to network connectivity issues, so you should try again (you won't be charged twice). If this problem persists, please let us know!`

However the transaction *is* processed successfully.

My code deviates from the example forms only because I'm validating the code using Parsely and want to generate the token only if the rest of the form is valid:

```
    if $(".error-block").length > 0 && $(".error-block").html() != ''
        $.scrollTo($(".error-block"))
    Stripe.setPublishableKey($('#stripe_key').val())
    stripeResponseHandler = (status, response)  ->
        if response.error
            $(".error-block").text(response.error.message)
            $('#join-button').attr("disabled", false).removeClass('disable').html('Join')
        else
            $form = $('#user_new')
            token = response['id']
            $('#user_stripe_token').val(token)
            $('#user_card_number').val('')
            $('#user_card_cvc').val('')
            $('#user_card_expiry_month').val('')
            $('#user_card_expiry_year').val('')
            $form.get(0).submit()
    $('#user_new').submit ->
        valid = $(@).parsley().isValid()
        if valid != false
            $('#join-button').attr("disabled", true).addClass('disable').html('Please wait...')
            Stripe.card.createToken({
                    number: $('#user_card_number').val(),
                    cvc: $('#user_card_cvc').val(),
                    exp_month: $('#user_card_expiry_month').val(),
                    exp_year: $('#user_card_expiry_year').val()
                    name: $('#user_first_name').val() + " " + $('#user_last_name').val()
                }, stripeResponseHandler)
            return false
        return false
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Does `$form.get(0).submit()` send you back into your `$('#user_new').submit ->` function? Am I missing something that lets your submit handler tell the browser that it can submit the form to the server?

Comment: @muistooshort mmm good point!! will check